# Italian Game: Two Knights Defense, Kloss Gambit (C57)

Tags: opening, learning, two-knights, italian-game

In my recent effort to play as many `Evan's Gambit` games and an ocassional `Lolli Attack`, I recently had this game as `White`:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Nf6 4. Ng5 d5 5. exd5 Nb4 6. Nc3 Nbxd5 7. Nxd5 Nxd5 
8. Nxf7 Kxf7 9. Qf3+ Ke8 10. Bxd5 Bd6 11. Qf7#
```

`5...Nb4` is the `Kloss Gambit` and I have never seen this move played against me so was curious how `White` should proceed?  Now I obviously played `6. Nc3` to add a defender to `d5`, but according to some databases, `White's` best move is `6. d6`.  I also noticed that there is only one game (although I am not completely sure of this) that has the move `5...Nb4` at [chessgames.com](http://www.chessgames.com) found [here](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1436343)

Comment: I'll try to add a full answer later, but for the time being, `6. d4!` is the best move.  Black cannot capture on d5.  White castles next move with a large edge.

Comment: Whoever voted to close, please explain why you think this is not a real question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I disagree with Andrew.

Why exactly `d4` is the best move? There is nothing wrong with it and in fact it is nice, but in my opinion 0-0 better. Other nice moves (d4 is in the list)

```
6) 0-0
6) d6
6) d4
```

Depending on what type of play do you prefer you can choose either of them.

0-0 is more aggressive. Idea behind it is that you are already one pawn up and there is no point to save that pawn. So you are developing (hiding your king and preparing to put the rook on e1 attacking the king of the opponent).
If your opponent is eating the pawn 
6 ... Nbxd5 
7. Re1

Here you are ready for an attack. This type of game if for a strategical opponent who can understand that material is not the most important and opening are for fast developing and getting initiative.

Idea behind d6 is easy. You are trying to maintain this pawn (actually you are forcing to exchange it). The f7 square is under attack and only reasonable way to save it is `6) ... Nbd5` which allows you to capture the pawn

```
7) dxc7 Qxc7
8) d3
```

In the end you are one move from castling (and nothing can stop you) and 1 pawn up. Your opponent is two moves and has one piece more developed than you.

With `d4`, as Andrew said d5 pawn is untouchable, and you are threatening e5 capture with attacking the knight. So if I were black, I would take `6) ... exd4` after which white would castle.

P.S how are you guys adding PNG?

Comment: Hi Salvador, there are directions for adding a replayer here: http://meta.chess.stackexchange.com/q/179/12